# Change pagination url format

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this:

```
example.com/blog/page/5
```

I want to change it to:

```
example.com/blog/page-5
```

I tried using a `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/page-([0-9]+) /blog/page/$1
```

but this returns 404 page not found. After a lot of debugging I realized that the reason it returns 404 is that the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP stays `blog/page-5` even after Apache rewrites it to `blog/page/5`.

It is possible to do it with redirection by adding `[R]` at the end of the `RewriteRule` but it will change the URL in browser to `/blog/page/5`, and I don't want that.

Any ideas?

Comment: "...the reason it returns 404 is that..." - The directive you posted is malformed and won't actually do anything, which is why you are are getting a 404 in this instance - apart from the other reason you mentioned. However, this isn't something you can do in `.htaccess`. You need to actually modify the URL that WordPress generates for pagination - within WordPress itself. You _might_ then use `.htaccess` to redirect the old URL for the benefit of SEO (but this isn't a functional requirement).

Comment: @MrWhite Yeah I wrote the directive from the top of my head so I messed it up. I edited it now. Any idea how modify theURL that WordPress generates for pagination?